# cte query - possible iteration to identify hierarchy in records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, iteration, common-table-expression

I asked a similar question before on this but my query has become more complicated.

I have the following query...

```
-- get all staff in chain of command...
DECLARE @staffid INT = '8';
WITH    n ( staffid, linemanagerid )
          AS ( SELECT   staffid ,
                        linemanagerid
               FROM     RM_Public.Hierarchy
               WHERE    staffid = @staffid
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   nplus1.staffid ,
                        nplus1.linemanagerid
               FROM     RM_Public.Hierarchy AS nplus1
                        INNER JOIN n ON n.staffid = nplus1.linemanagerid
             ),
        m ( staffid, linemanagerid )
          AS ( SELECT   staffid ,
                        linemanagerid
               FROM     RM_Public.Hierarchy
               WHERE    staffid = @staffid
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   nplus1.staffid ,
                        nplus1.linemanagerid
               FROM     RM_Public.Hierarchy AS nplus1
                        INNER JOIN m ON m.linemanagerid = nplus1.staffid
             )
    SELECT  HierarchyID ,
            LineManagerID ,
            StaffID
    FROM    RM_Public.Hierarchy
    WHERE   staffid IN ( SELECT staffid
                         FROM   n
                         UNION
                         SELECT staffid
                         FROM   m )
```

which yields the following table:

```
id  lineManagerID    staffID    changeable
16  9                8          
19  8                7
20  8                6
21  6                5
24  NULL             9
```

So, at present I only have lineManagerID and StaffID. I would like to set the Change column to 'y' or 'n' depending on whether or not the staff or lineManagers are below a given staffID in the the chain of command.

For example... from the point of view of staffid = 8 the table would look like

```
id  lineManagerID    staffID    changeable
16  9                8          y
19  8                7          y
20  8                6          y
21  6                5          y
24  NULL             9          n
```

So the column is marked 'y' if staffid = 8 or the staffid is a lineManager in the chain of command for a staffid below it... does that make sense?
It should be marked as 'n' if the staffid doesn't have authority over those higher in the chain. Since 9 is 8's manager then 8 has no authority to change 9's line manager. I hope that is clear enough.

Hope you guys can help.

Thanks.
DS

Comment: Can you provide us with some sample input data and the corresponding desired output?

Comment: cant just do a simple case statement?